# Array to string conversion: user migration file

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

For my package, I'm trying to create multiple columns in my `users` database table.

My table name variables are defined like this:

```
private function fields()
{
    return $this->fields = [
        'id' => [
            'type' => 'increments',
        ],
       'name' => [
           'type' => 'string',
           'length' => 250,
       ],
       'email' => [
           'type' => 'string',
           'length' => 250,
           'extra' => 'unique'
       ],
       'password' => [
           'type' => 'string',
           'length' => 100,
       ],
       'access_token' => [
           'type' => 'string',
           'length' => 255,
       ],
       'remember_token' => [
           'type' => 'string',
           'length' => 100,
       ],
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to loop through this via a foreach loop like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table) {
    foreach ($this->fields as $field => $value) {
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('users', $field)) {
            var_dump(gettype($value['type']));
            $table->$value['type']($field);
        }
    }
});
```

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I receive an error: `Array to string conversion`

The `$value['type']` part is the issue. So I know the issue, but can't figure out how to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to save it to a variable like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table) {
    foreach ($this->fields as $field => $value) {
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('users', $field)) {
            $type = $value['type'];
            $table->$type($field);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh! I've tried putting it in a variable like this `$type = $value`, I forgot the `['type']`. Thanks for your help!